# Question on Typescipt interfaces and computed properties (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a computer property on a typescript interface, but I just can't seem to figure it out...I am probably just overlooking something simple 'cause I am at the point of frustration and when I get to that point I lose focus ;/

> member.model.ts

```
interface MemberName {
  given: string;
  family: string;
  preferred?: string;
}

interface MemberModel {
  id: string;
  name: MemberName;
  readonly displayName?: () => string; 
}

export class Member implements MemberModel {
  public id: string;
  public name: MemberName;

  displayName?(): string {
    return this.name.preferred ?? `${ this.name.given } ${ this.name.family }`;
  }
}
```

> member.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Member } from '../models/member';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MemberService {
  public member: Member;

  constructor() {
    this.member = {
      id: 'test',
      name: {
        given: 'Unknown',
        family: 'User'
      }
    }
  }

  login() {
    this.member.name.given = 'Authenticated';
    this.member.name.family = 'Member';
    console.log('login', this.member)
  }

  logout() {
    this.member.name.given = 'Anonymous';
    this.member.name.family = 'Member';
    console.log('logout', this.member);
  }
}
```

I can call `memberService.login()` and it returns

```
id: 'test',
name: {
  given: 'Authenticated',
  family: 'Member'
}
```

I can call `memberService.logout()` and it returns

```
id: 'test',
name: {
  given: 'Anonymous',
  family: 'Member'
}
```

...but I can't seem to get the `displayName` computed property to show no matter what I try?!?

Comment: Yea, I hit something very similar when I was trying to send a payload via POST and my `get`ers weren't coming through. You have to create some sort of `.toJSON` method or something that will return an actual object with the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code `Member` is a class, and you won't get a class **instance** by just assigning a simple javascript object to a field. as I see you've added a ? here `displayName?()`. I believe you've done that becase you couldn't assign an object to a ts class "asserion". if you want `this.member` to have a method you should put there a class instance instead, and then, fill it with fields. somehow like that would work:

```
 constructor() {
   this.member = new Member();
   Object.assign(this.member, {/*... any fields you like */});
 }
```

now you can remove that odd `?` in the method name 
 
also it is not clear how would you like to refer to `displayName` property.
if you want it as a method than your version is  fine, but if you want it as a computed property, then you can define getter with a `get` keyword like this

```
get displayName(): string {
    return this.name.preferred ?? `${ this.name.given } ${ this.name.family }`;
 }
```

Comment: yeah the "odd ? in the method name" was weird to me too, but it was the only way I could get it to compile without errors

Answer (score 1):

You need to create some method within your class that will return an object with your value. It's very similar to the way `get`ters aren't returned in the same way.

Here's an example of what's happening:

```js
class Sample {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
  }
  get bar() { return `${this.foo} and from getter` };
  
  toObj() {
    return { ...this, bar: this.bar };
  }
}

const samp = new Sample();

console.log(samp); // bar nor present
console.log(samp.bar); // but it's there?
console.log(JSON.stringify(samp)); // but it's not there!
console.log(samp.toObj()); // it's there!
```